# Tic Tac Toe AI with Machine Learning

Tags: machine-learning, algorithms, reinforcement-learning, games

I am new to machine learning and as one of my first projects I decided to make a tic tac toe bot. What I've done so far is a rgb/hex color recognition with the naive bayes algorithm, which was really simple to make. Now I am struggling a bit with making a tic tac toe bot.

My question is how should I proceed with this, is there a dataset, and should I take naive bayes again, or decision tree would be better for tic tac toe? (once again, purpose is just that I learn and dive deeper in machine learning)

Comment: Tic-Tac-Toe is a [solved game](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solved_game). Why would one need ML to make a Tic-Tac-Toe bot?

Comment: It is solved in the sense that there is an optimal strategy that guarantees at least a draw.  But for someone who never has seen the game and doesn,t know that strategy there may be a way for them to learn it.

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo That makes it a good ML project because we can see if an AI solves the game.

Comment: I am not sure that designing a bot for a game is necessarily the best starting project for Machine learning, because playing a game is a bit a more involved (because of the dependence on the play of the opponent). Yes, the bot could have a few key parts implemented by ML algorithms (such as evaluation of the position quality), or making proposal moves but combining this together could be somewhat tricky.

Comment: Like I said, the purpose is rather diving into ML. I am trying to start simple, so if you guys also have any similar "mini-projects" that could help me move forward, I would appreciate this. I am already doing the machine learning courses in coursera and udacity :)

Comment: I've added the [tag:reinforcement-learning] tag because self-teaching game-playing AI is what RL does best. I'm sure that an introductory textbook to RL would cover how to build a tic-tac-toe-playing AI as an example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Presumably you don't want an AI which looks ahead a few moves and brute-forces the best move. I guess you want an AI which will evaluate the strength of each possible move and choose the best.

One way you can approach this is to train an AI to take an input of the board and an input of where to play next and output a probability that this move will lead to a win.

You can create your own data by playing this AI against itself or against a player which plays randomly. This is more involved than using a dataset with the best moves listed for many positions, it's an option if you can't find such a dataset or if you want a challenge.

One possible way to create your own data and use it to iteratively improve the AI is the following:

1. Let the AI play a few moves and then pause the game
2. Select a random move to play (random allows the AI to learn from moves it wouldn't normally make)
3. Record the state of the game and the new move
4. Let the AI finish the game and record the result

This approach will create game data with many positions and many actions taken with the expected win/loss/draw result. You can use this data to train an AI to predict the result of the game if a given move is played. Repeat this training cycle to iteratively improve the AI.

Comment: Under "input of the board" and "input of where to play next" you mean the current state of the board and next possible move by the AI? Thank you for helping me figure out the way how I could create the data set myself.

Comment: @Jannet Yes I did mean the current state of the board and the next move. I think that recording the current state of the board would require 18 variables, 9 binary variables indicating whether a square has an X or not, and 9 more binary variables indicating whether a square has an O or not.

Comment: So one feature would be the state of the board. As I am trying to connect it to my previous experience (rgb/hex color recognition where I had features and labels) in this case the one feature is the state of the board. As it has 9 places, we could actually show each place with 0 (empty) 1 (enemy mark) and 2 (my mark). 

As for the labels, I had rough time figuring them out (as for me the case is supervised learning), what could they be? Do not get me wrong, I understand the very general algorithm, but am trying to connect it to previous experience so I can get to implement it.

Comment: I also thought for the starting phase of the game, when there is no clear win/lose/tie outcome, how the moves and their probability should be calculated, seems too much information for me now, so I am trying to organize and figure it all out

Answer (score 3):

I am working on a very similar project to you, and I'm also doing it as an introduction to machine learning.

One of the best methods I've seen for getting a tic-tac-toe AI is a reinforcement learning method described in [this paper](https://users.auth.gr/kehagiat/Research/GameTheory/12CombBiblio/TicTacToe.pdf) and formally discussed in [this book](http://webdocs.cs.ualberta.ca/~sutton/book/ebook/).

Basically, you have a program run through possible moves and then update probability of how likely that move is to be correct based on whether or not it ends up winning when playing against a random player.

If the player is not random, or you would like a more formal analysis, you can use minimax or [alpha-beta pruning](http://web.cs.ucla.edu/~rosen/161/notes/alphabeta.html) as detailed [here](http://www.cas.mcmaster.ca/~gk/courses/project2016.pdf). Then, I'd recommend training a neural network on the data you've received for an additional challenge.

You can also use more advanced methods such as the [Monte Carlo Tree Search](https://spin.atomicobject.com/2015/12/12/monte-carlo-tree-search-algorithm-game-ai/) (similar to the reinforcement learning method above).

Answer (score 0):

I have just finished making a tictactoe bot.

The way I have set it up is that it learns from the moves that I make.

So, if I'm playing a PlayervsAI or PlayervsPlayer game, every move that the winner makes is recorded and saved in a file. So this data is essentially 'moves that lead up to a win'. The format of this data is the 'state of the board + position played'

So when the AI is playing, it looks at this data, sees if the current state of the board matches any in the saved moves file, then plays that move. If it cant find a match it just looks for a win, or a block or just random.

As TicTacToe has an optimal strategy, technically you could input all the optimal moves manually, but I found it more interesting 'teaching' the AI.